# Jquery .ui-widget :active { outline: none; } behaviour in firefox

Tags: jquery

Hi in one of xhtml page containing select box having more that 10000 option list I am facing one  issue select box opening at slow speed in firefox3.5 working fine in IE 7/8

When I remove this class .ui-widget :active { outline: none; } from JQuery UI CSS

its started to work fine in Firefox 3.5. Any idea for this behavior?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, 'outline' wasn't supported by IE7.  As far as IE8, if you're not running in standards mode then it will ignore the property.  So technically, it works fine in IE 7/8 because it is being ignored.

It's probably slow in FF because rendering 10,000 items in a select list is a really bad idea, performance wise.  Consider ways you can limit the number of options and performance will probably increase.  As a test, try 10 options and see if you still experience slow speeds.